# Unauthorised error:401 Kafka schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send some sample records along with schema in my kafka topic.
On line producer.send(record) I am facing unauthorised error?

I have provided the basic auth details and url in my config.
Also, I have assigned all kind of roles to the topic.

What could be missing and why is it not allowing me to send records?

Comment: @onecricketeer any suggestions please?

Comment: Show a [mcve], please

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution. I am also stuck with a similar issues. here is the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75174381/how-to-rotate-confluent-cloud-keys-api-keys-through-terraform-of-keys-are-delete/75174548#75174548

Answer (score 0):

Provide your details log then we can take are deeper look. Basically you should double check the config related to producer:

- tls enable or not
- client-id (if you might enable transactional)
- ACL for the target topic (write permission)